# Convert spark dataframe with string column to StructType column

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a `CSV` file with a header as "message" and rows as

```
{"a":1,"b":"hello 1","c":"1234"}
{"a":2,"b":"hello 2","c":"2345"}
```

I want to convert them in different columns `a,b,c`.
I tried the following code:

```
df1 = spark.read.format("csv").option("header","true")
      .option("delimiter","^")
      .option("inferSchema","false")
      .load("testing.csv")
```

But it is taking it as a `string` column.

```
df1.printScema() --> String
```

Comment: This looks like json not csv

Comment: This we got as a csv file format, not a json file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file is in json format, with the first line as "message".
The first line can be ignored using the option `"DROPMALFORMED"` while reading using Spark's `DataFrameReader`

```
file : json-test.txt

message
{"a":1,"b":"hello 1","c":"1234"}
{"a":2,"b":"hello 2","c":"2345"}
```

***reading a json file by ignoring bad records [initial record]:***

```
val jsondf = spark.read
                  .option("multiLine", false)
                  .option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED")
                  .json("files/file-reader-test/json-test.txt")
jsondf.show()
```

***output:***

```
+---+-------+----+
|  a|      b|   c|
+---+-------+----+
|  1|hello 1|1234|
|  2|hello 2|2345|
+---+-------+----+
```

***schema :***

```
jsondf.printSchema()

root
 |-- a: long (nullable = true)
 |-- b: string (nullable = true)
 |-- c: string (nullable = true)
```